# what shasum: elasticsearch-5.0.0.deb.sha1: no properly formatted SHA1 checksum lines found means?

Tags: elasticsearch, sha1, checksum, sha, elasticsearch-5

I want to install elasticsearch5.6.4 on ubuntu 17.10. So I downloaded elasticsearch.deb and elasticsearch.deb.sha1. As the sturcture said in [this guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/deb.html), after I run

```
shasum -a 512 -c elasticsearch-6.2.1.tar.gz.sha512
```

I have gotten this error:

```
shasum: elasticsearch-5.6.4.deb.sha1: no properly formatted SHA1 checksum lines found
```

What does this error mean? and what should I do?

Answer (score 5):

This answer is not so much for the OP (who is hopefully sorted now) but any passers by who encounter the error in the question.

The error

```
shasum: [CHECKSUM_FILENAME] : no properly formatted SHA[TYPE] checksum lines found
```

indicates that the checksum file passed to the -c flag is **not formatted** as
follows

```
a67eb6eeeff63ac77d34c2c86b0a3fa97f69a9d3f8c9d34c20036fa79cb4214d  ./kbld-linux-amd64
```

Where

- the first field is **the expected checksum**,
- the second field is a ' ' character indicating that the file is to be checked as a text file (as opposed to being checked as a binary file or being checked in Universal mode which ignores newlines)
- and the third field is **the name of the file you likely just downloaded** and whose integrity you want to verify

So in the example above the developers who created kbld [supplied the above text on their release page](https://github.com/k14s/kbld/releases/tag/v0.7.0) to show the checksums that they calculated after they built the kbld binaries for various platforms.

I added the line for the linux build to a file called `kbld_v0_7_0.checksum` and then I ran the following in the directory where I downloaded the kbld-linux-amd64 binary

```
$ shasum -c kbld_v0_7_0.checksum -a 256
./kbld-linux-amd64: OK
```

The OK from shasum shows that the binary that I downloaded, `./kbld-linux-amd64` , generates the same sha256 checksum that was produced when the developers did their build which indicates that the files are, in all likelihood, identical

Answer (score 3):

You are correct and I'm a bit puzzled (since I've written that section in the Elastic docs): `shasum -a 512` works on other operating systems and checking the man page, I would have thought it should do the same on Ubuntu:

```
-a, --algorithm   1 (default), 224, 256, 384, 512, 512224, 512256

When verifying SHA-512/224 or SHA-512/256 checksums, indicate the
algorithm explicitly using the -a option, e.g.

  shasum -a 512224 -c checksumfile
```

I'm not sure why `shasum -a 512` doesn't work here, but these 3 alternatives all give you the correct result:

- `shasum -c elasticsearch-6.2.1.deb.sha512 -a 512`
- `shasum -a 512256 -c elasticsearch-6.2.1.deb.sha512`
- `sha512sum -c elasticsearch-6.2.1.deb.sha512`